# Como corregir el error Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Reader_Exception'

Tags: php, phpexcel

estoy tratando de enviar dos valores a dos celdas en un excel YA CREADO, que tiene de nombre consulta.xlsx ... pero resulta que me sale el siguiente error:

```
  Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Reader_Exception' with message 'Could not open consulta.xlsx for reading! File does not exist.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\importexcel\lib\PHPExcel\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel2007.php:343 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\importexcel\f.php(15): PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007->load('consulta.xlsx') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\importexcel\lib\PHPExcel\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel2007.php on line 343
```

mi archivo excel lo tengo almacenado en mi escritorio, y estoy usando excel 2010

el codigo es el siguiente:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_time_limit(0);

 date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
 set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'lib/PHPExcel/');

 require_once 'lib/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
 $fileType = 'Excel2007';
 $fileName = 'consulta.xlsx';

  // Read the file
  $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($fileType);
  $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($fileName);

  // Change the file
  $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello')
        ->setCellValue('B1', 'World!');

  // Write the file
  $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, $fileType);
   $objWriter->save($fileName);

 ?>
```

Comment: Esa libreria esta deprecated ahora se esta empleando PhpSpreadsheet

Comment: Hola, el error es claro no puede encontrar el archivo. Posiblemente el directorio de $fileName es incorrecto. Sí no me equivoco esta esperando el archivo consulta.xlsx en el directorio C:\xampp\htdocs\importexcel\lib\PHPExcel\PHPExcel\Reader

Comment: Si,ya habia encontrado el error, solo faltaba poner bien la direccion del excel... pero ahora el error que pasa es el siguiente, solo me deja subir información cuando el excel está cerrado, pero cuando el excel esta abierto no se puede realizar, y me muestra un error... sabe porque se da?